# Why ToolStripItem can't handle big numbers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a recursive funcion that search for folders.

```
    private int contFiles = 0;
    private List<string> GetFiles(string folder, string filter)
    {
        var files = new List<string>();
        Action<string> getFilesInDir = null;
        getFilesInDir = new Action<string>(dir =>
        {
            contFiles++;
            tslQuant.Text = contFiles.ToString(); //ToolStripItem
            try
            {
                // get all the files in this directory
                files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter));                   
                // and recursively visit the directories
                foreach (var subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                {
                    getFilesInDir(subdir);
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uae.Message);
            }
        });
        getFilesInDir(folder);
        return files;
    }
```

The function increments contFiles and set that number to a ToolStripItem, but I'm Always getting "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException".

**How can I increase this value (up to 5000) and display in a TSI?**

ERROR:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Index was out of range. It must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
  Parameter name: index"

Source="mscorlib"
  ParamName="index"
  StackTrace:
       in System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip.WndProc(Message& m) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m) 
       in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) 
  InnerException:

### EDIT

After Reading up the whole code of the program, I notice that the funcion is being caled inside a Do_Work, so I'm using a

```
backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress((1));
```

to report aaand everything is working.

**I don't know WHY, but somehow, the toolStripItem can be accessed even inside a backgroundWorker, labels and others controls can't.**

Comment: ToolStripItem knows nothing about numbers at all. Try setting that to "xxxxxx" and see what happens.

Comment: Everything is ok with "xxxxxx", the program crashes with 300... It says index of toolStripItem is out of bounds...

Comment: The code you posted cannot be causing that error. Are you adding the list of files to the ToolStrip?

Comment: My toolstripItem only have the number.

Comment: OK then, what is the value of `contFiles.ToString()` when it errors out?

Comment: Sometimes 541, others 690... (Same folder, same filter)

Comment: Clearly @JohnSaunders is right.  Problem is somewhere else.  Are you drawing these Tool items yourself by any chance?

Comment: No, it's from toolbox

Comment: Oh, something that I forgot to say, I'm using a backgroundWorker, but somehow I can alter toolStrip values.

Comment: Well, don't do that then.  Update the text of the menu item in the WorkerCompleted event, not during it.

Comment: Somehow, you are adding to the number of ToolStripItems. It's the indexer of the collection which is failing.

Comment: Guys, it's working using ReportProgress, and showing inside a ProgressChanged.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you never reset the `contFiles` variable back to zero.  And if you call the `GetFiles()` several times you may get in problems.  So you may want to reset it back to zero here

```
    contFiles = 0;    // Reset variable to prevent overflow 
    var files = new List<string>();
    Action<string> getFilesInDir = null;
    getFilesInDir = new Action<string>(dir =>
    { ...
```

Comment: no, same problem. 
Using the same toolStripItem to show another number that increases fast and a lot don't crashes the program.